# Infinite loop with mod_rewrite and vhost_alias

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I made myself a dynamic vhost file for all directories in /home/lukasz/websites

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName vm01.dev
        ServerAlias *.vm01.dev

        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "lukasz"

        VirtualDocumentRoot /home/lukasz/websites/%1/public
        <directory /home/lukasz/websites/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
        </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It works well until very simple rule from mod_rewrite comes to play. If I add following code to the .htacesss

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The apache server will be unable to respond. It will go into an infinite loop and will break out from the execution after 10 redirects. This problem is tightly related to VirtualDocumentRoot I'm using. How should I modify my config to keep it dynamic and stop it breaking with about htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to make **index.php** the default page, when the requested resource doesn't exist, you didn't say.

If this is the case then adding an **ErrorDocument** entry to your **virtualHost** will suffice e.g.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

If you are going to use mod_rewrite, it's far more efficient to place the rules in the Virtualhost definition than in a .htaccess file. As the *httpd.conf* is read once at start-up and all rule compiled, as opposed to the .htaccess file being read and all rules parsed for each request. Anyway the following should stop the loop:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

Assuming you have an: **/index.php**

**FYI:** The Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation is worth a read if your unclear as to what the above rules do, or if you want something a little more abstract consider the following [post](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Web_Servers/Apache/A_4043).

Comment: An explanation would have been nice. Why does the example work, but the OP's doesn't? Only thing stopping me from downvoting is the fact that the example provided fixed my problem. No idea why.